# Error in my javascript file

Tags: javascript, java

***Code:***

```
  <%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
```

***Error message:***

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - Syntax error on tokens, delete      these tokens
> - Syntax error on tokens, ( expected      instead

***Code:***

```
var tabMessages = new Array();
```

***Error message:***

> Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression

***My JS file:***

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>

var tabMessages = new Array();

tabMessages['errors.invalid']='<bean:message key="errors.invalid" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['errors.maxlength']='<bean:message key="errors.maxlength" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['errors.minlength']='<bean:message key="errors.minlength" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['errors.range']='<bean:message key="errors.range" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['errors.required']='<bean:message key="errors.required" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['errors.byte']='<bean:message key="errors.byte" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['errors.date']='<bean:message key="errors.date" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['errors.double']='<bean:message key="errors.double" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['errors.float']='<bean:message key="errors.float" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['errors.integer']='<bean:message key="errors.integer" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['errors.long']='<bean:message key="errors.long" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['errors.short']='<bean:message key="errors.short" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['errors.creditcard']='<bean:message key="errors.creditcard" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['errors.email']='<bean:message key="errors.email" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['errors.numeric']='<bean:message key="errors.numeric" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['errors.filetype']='<bean:message key="errors.filetype" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['errors.accord.nonvalide']='<bean:message key="affichagePaa.erreur.accord.nonvalide" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['errors.telephone']='<bean:message key="errors.telephone" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['errors.incorrectYear']='<bean:message key="error.incorrectYear" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';


tabMessages['errors.dateCumulAnnuelDepassee']='<bean:message key="declaration.saisieCARealise.validationCumulAnnuel.possibleALaBonneDate.erreur" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['errors.dateCumulAnnuelEnCours']='<bean:message key="declaration.saisieCARealise.validationCumulAnnuel.dateOK.erreur" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['errors.dateCumulAnnuelNonAtteinte']='<bean:message key="declaration.saisieCARealise.validationCumulAnnuel.dateDepassee.erreur" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['errors.cumulAnnuelDejaValide']='<bean:message key="declaration.saisieCARealise.validationCumulAnnuel.dej�Valider.erreur" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';

tabMessages['negociation.suppression.ristourne']='<bean:message key="negociation.suppression.ristourne" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['changement.champApplication.ristourne']='<bean:message key="negociation.AjoutRistourne.changement.champApplication.ristourne" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['matrice.suppression.familleaSuivre']='<bean:message key="matrice.suppression.familleaSuivre" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';

tabMessages['alerte.suppression.simple']='<bean:message key="alerte.suppression.simple" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';
tabMessages['alerte.suppression.complexe']='<bean:message key="alerte.suppression.complexe" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';

tabMessages['cumul.annuel.temporaire']='<bean:message key="cumul.annuel.temporaire" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';

tabMessages['calcul.retrocession.type.retrocession.differente']='<bean:message key="calcul.retrocession.type.retrocession.differente" arg0="{0}" arg1="{1}" arg2="{2}" arg3="{3}" arg4="{4}" />';


function getMessage(key, arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) {
    var res = tabMessages[key];
    if (arg0 != undefined) {
        res = res.replace(/\{0\}/g, arg0);
    }
    if (arg1 != undefined) {
        res = res.replace(/\{1\}/g, arg1);
    }
    if (arg2 != undefined) {
        res = res.replace(/\{2\}/g, arg2);
    }
    if (arg3 != undefined) {
        res = res.replace(/\{3\}/g, arg3);
    }
    if (arg4 != undefined) {
        res = res.replace(/\{4\}/g, arg4);
    }
    return res;
}
```

[image]

what is wrong ..?

Comment: are you mixing jsp and js?

Comment: @redflar3 yes i mixing jsp and js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using JSP code in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633669/using-jsp-code-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Mixing jsp and JS can and/or will produce unexepected results. One way is collecting all JSP related variables in one place and factoring out non-JSP codes into another pure/static JavaScript files.

Comment: Could be. Could also be the way JSP's and JS mixes together. It's hard to know but it's almost common to find this kind of bug with JSP + JS together. You're code looks okay at first sight, so you might want to check other places for the culprit. The error message you got feels like you haven't done anything wrong though.